# Need help to find Selenium Webdriver contents and the learning sites

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner to **Selenium Webdriver**.I know some basics of it but don't have whole contents about selenium webdriver with me which I should learn.I also know java and its concepts very well.So, I preferably want to learn selenium in java.

Is there any one who could help me with the contents and the learning sites which are free for selenium learning? I have done lot of reasearch on selenium webdriver but most of the sites provide paid learning for selenium. I want to learn selenium by self. So, if I could get any site which provides **free** **video tutorials** for all contents then it will be heaven for me. 
Thanks in advance!

(CurrentlyIi am doing job as manual tester but I want to move my career into automation field and thought selenium is the best way to start with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Following links will help you to get detail idea about selenium :**

1 - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

2 - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

3 - http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

**Following link will help you to get selenium code examples :**

[Selenium code examples with tutorial](http://www.toolsqa.com/)

**Following link will help you to get selenium code examples with video tutorials:**

[Selenium tutorial with some vidoes](http://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html)

Comment: happy to help. cheers :)